# Error with Sharing Images in android

Tags: java, android, image, share

In android I can not share Images in jpeg as well as in png format. Please help and correct my code

whenever i code for share it gives exception "File format not supported"
This is my code:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.parekh.shareimage/drawable");
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My sample image text");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: That code points to a directory

Comment: Beyond that, relatively few apps handle the `android.resource` scheme well. And, not every app will handle *both* `EXTRA_TEXT` *and* `EXTRA_STREAM`.

Comment: Pls correct my code

Comment: That depends on where you are getting your images from

Comment: I'm new in android can you give me a link or a website from where can i learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your drawable image into you internal storage and select that image. This way will help you.

```
try{

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shareforma);
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "forma.PNG");
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String msgText = "Sample Message";

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");

    //set your message
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msgText); 

    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image_name.jpg";

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, msgText));
```

Comment: Bro if i have around 50 images then how will i pass **R.drawable.shareforma** ??? Need Help

Comment: For a single image this method will be suitable. For, multiple images you should go with other alternates, try to store image in sqlite db and retrive or try to use firebase or parse cloud service.

Comment: Is there any other **code** beside sqlite db or firebase or parse which you have mentioned

Comment: Use sqlite db to store images.  http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/10/insert-and-retrieve-image-into-db.html

Comment: Actually whenever i click share on **Image1** my first Image is shared properly. But when i click share on **Image2** my first Image gets fetched.Same with Image3, 4, 5... My app is very basic..Need help??

Comment: mm make sure you giving different names for all images.

Comment: Write a function with one string parameter like 
public void shareImage(String filePath){ 
// put your share image cod here
// replace image path with your parameter
}

Now pass your image path here .. you can get share all images.

Comment: Example - Whenever i swipe to any image (eg. Image1,image2.....) and i liked say( image3) so i wanna share that image. So when i click share image3 so the code should share image3.

Comment: For that use some logic. Try to write function and call it whenever you swipe the image pass that image path to that function as parameter.

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thanks for sharing.